# YouTube API not loading videos after uploaded to the play store youtube_player_flutter plugin

Tags: flutter, youtube-api

I created an app which plays YouTube videos using the YouTube API and the "youtube_player_flutter" plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter). Testing on IOS simulator and on Android real device it worked fine, but after uploading to the play store and downloading it, it doesn't load the videos. It seems it has been blocked for some reason. Has any of you been through the same situation or have any lights on what could be causing this API not working? Thanks in advance for your support!

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you request the internet access, some permissions are bypassed on debug mode but not release.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Thanks Murat, but it's already permitted. It loads some content from firebase, but when it comes to the video it doesn't.